# How can I assign type predicates to variable

Tags: typescript

I have a code:

```
let point: number | undefined;
let point2: number;

const isPointNotUndefined = point !== undefined;
if (isPointNotUndefined) {
  point2 = point;
}
```

And TypeScript says that "`Type 'number | undefined'` is not assignable to type `number`" But if I do next:

```
if (point !== undefined) {
  point2 = point;
}
```

this works fine.

How can I explain typescript to do a type predicate in the variable, without creating a function ?

Comment: "*How can I explain typescript to do a type predicate in the variable, without creating a function ?*" short answer: you cannot.

Comment: Why do you need to save whether or not the `point` variable is defined, in a variable ?

Comment: @Nicolas very likely to prevent the compilation error.

Comment: @Nicolas I would like to have some boolean variables, e.g. pointExists, minMaxExists, pointBetweenMinMax and I want to use it in the condition: 
if ( pointExists && minMaxExists && pointBetweenMinMax) 
and I don't want to create addition function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE FOR TS4.4:

TypeScript 4.4 will introduce support for saving the results of certain type guards to a `const`, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#44730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730).  Unfortunately, the particular example you have here will continue not to work, because `point` is a mutable variable, and the compiler does not spend the resources necessary to ensure that `point` is not actually reassigned between the assignment of `isPointNotUndefined` and when you check it.  If you make `point` a `const` or a function parameter, then the compiler will assume that `point` is not reassigned and `isPointNotUndefined` will be used as a type guard:

```
function foo(point: number | undefined) {
  let point2: number;
  const isPointNotUndefined = point !== undefined;
  if (isPointNotUndefined) {
    point2 = point; // okay
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-dev.20210701#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4CgkkAbCAFyRgHsNgyAuJYAVzACMI0kAfJZ4ACYQAZrQgCA3IRLlKNOgCZGLdpynT4VYFAoYoABXlkAclTIBVQSLECkAXjm0KAQjsP+Q0cHFSiGYUgAFHqGTqYWVl7iAJR40kTUTgr2jnQSSAD0GUg6GMTESJxoVGjSAL74+BX4oJCwCMgAYhgAHnFEwvzwZBhaSMJUVIGJdMqsHFy8HtbeArG4RETxMhQjZEpM42rLmtq6Bkbhlp42KWtIru6RNr6L-kEhh2bHMzHtiwlGyQ5r6VlIVAA1iAAJ7LCpECplIA)

### ANSWER FOR TS4.3 AND BELOW:

Storing the results of a type guard in a boolean variable is not currently possible in TypeScript.  There are two open feature requests in GitHub for this: [microsoft/TypeScript#12184](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184) and [microsoft/TypeScript#24865](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24865).  According to a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184#issuecomment-260162839) by the lead architect of TypeScript,

> This would require us to track what effects a particular value for one variable implies for *other* variables, which would add a good deal of complexity (and associated performance penalty) to the control flow analyzer. Still, we'll keep it as a suggestion.

So it is unlikely to be implemented any time soon, unless someone can suggest a way to do it that doesn't significantly degrade compiler performance.  If you have such a proposal, you might want to go to #24865 and present it.  Otherwise you could always give each of them a  to add another vote for it, but pragmatically speaking you should proceed as if this will never happen.

---

The workarounds for this are ones you already know and don't want to use.  For completeness, you could perform the check inline:

```
if (point !== undefined) {
  point2 = point;
}
```

or if the check is something cumbersome to write out, make a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) for it:

```
const isDefined = <T,>(x: T | undefined): x is T => typeof x !== "undefined";
if (isDefined(point)) {
  point2 = point;
}
```

---

Since checking for `undefined` is so quick, I doubt any other workaround is going to be less cumbersome.  Still, another way to go would be to represent any "check-for-validity-and-value" operation as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions), such as this:

```
type DefinedUnion<T> =
  { defined: true, value: Exclude<T, undefined> } |
  { defined: false, value: undefined };
```

Discriminated unions have the advantage of storing the "check" as a discriminant property.  Of course, getting a value into the form of a `DefinedUnion` takes some more code:

```
function toDefinedUnion<T>(x: T | undefined): DefinedUnion<T> {
  return { defined: typeof x !== "undefined", value: x } as DefinedUnion<T>
}   

const pointU = toDefinedUnion(point);
```

But then it's easy to use.

```
if (pointU.defined) {
  point2 = pointU.value; // okay
}
```

Again, this is *not* what I'd suggest to replace a single "is this `undefined`" check.  But if your "is this a valid thing" check is expensive enough that you really only want to do it once, a discriminated union might be the way to go.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/DYUwLgBADg9glgOzALgggrgWwEYgE4QA+E6CAJiAGaIhkDcAUKJLImAEyoY76MMDGMBAGdIcYQAV4SAHIwwAVXJUaZCAF5o0yAEJ1m0hWoJajOJQgAKVkgh6Dy47QCUEAN4MIWtuw3ekjAC+DAJCohDiACIqJmqaADwAKgA0AHyWAB6oiUQkjqrOqBkRwhA56qkQYACeUCAwFsX2EABEhjG0LWYWllEdZNbazq4eXjYcfuNBITV1ENFOZEpwQkmV6p7uEEaqqGB46CDJEABuAIbAh6gAohn8lxRJx+2LlYFEm27b-aiUF8JHU4XK55HaxCCBPiUUj8MArBBVGALVTLVaJdJZMq5F4FVDI2KohBrdybPDgdB4BFfMG0Pa1eqNOz6Vo42ItY7nS4gIoQiBnUr42iEtYMYKhEQsbQKPxgJH9QmDNjObpWcYKAB0NLII02418mjV6s5hzoEAA9GaIDAANZnaqihhAA)